# How to run Tomcat on Linux (which has glassfish on port 8080)

Tags: apache, unix, tomcat, glassfish

I am trying to run to tomcat on linux where glassfish is already running on port 8080 ( you can check here - vhost2.cs.rit.edu:8080 . So i changed the tomcat port to 8181 by editing the server.xml file. NOw with the command startup.sh and i get the following  output

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/krs8785/apache-tomcat-7.0.54
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/krs8785/apache-tomcat-7.0.54
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/krs8785/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/krs8785/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/krs8785/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

I am assuming that tomcat is now working. Now when i test the server by - vhost3.cs.rit.edu:8181 I get

```
No data received on the browser.
```

What is the problem here and how do i solve it?

Comment: When i run the command bin/startup.sh I get Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/krs8785/apache-tomcat-7.0.54
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/krs8785/apache-tomcat-7.0.54
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/krs8785/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/krs8785/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/krs8785/apache-tomcat-7.0.54/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
Does it mean its working ? If yes now when I  go to vhost2.cs.rit.edu:8181 it shows NO DATA REVICED

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be unrelated to tomcat. I think your first step should be to exclude networking issues.

I have assumed you are accessing vhost3.cs.rit.edu:8181 from another machine. If that is the case, try to access localhost:8181 from vhost3.cs.rit.edu. If this is not possible in a conventional browser, perhaps because it is a headless server with X forwarding disabled then use a terminal based browser. Try typing the following in the terminal on vhost3.cs.rit.edu

```
lynx localhost:8181
```

If you are able to see a representation of a tomcat splash page then you can attribute it to networking issues. This could be firewall related (perhaps even an issue with iptables on linux).